# directory separator in cakephp disables my CSS

Tags: css, cakephp

is what I get, everytime I use this,

```
$certpath = APP."Plugin".DS."PaypalIpn".DS."Controller".DS."Certificates".DS;
```

in my code, it ruins my css. Well, not necessarily ruins but my page is as if not using any css for its alignment or other stuff.

i need that DS since i have to call a file in that directory

```
$encryption['cert_file'] = $certpath.$encryption['cert_file'];
```

I tried this:

```
$encryption['key_file'] = $certpath.DS.$encryption['key_file'];
$encryption['cert_file'] = $certpath.DS.$encryption['cert_file'];
$encryption['paypal_cert_file'] = $certpath.DS.$encryption['paypal_cert_file'];
```

Still no luck. The first two lines work that way,  but the third one doesn't.

And I tried googling with these keywords:

```
directory separator in cakephp ruins my css
uses of directory separator in cakephp
calling files using directory separator in cakephp
```

but none of it helped me.

DS is just a directory separator right? What could possibly be wrong?

.......... edited part

well this is another issue, I found the culprit from my previous issue but please do explain so how it is related to my problem. this is my PaypalHelper.php

```
<?php

$importConfig = array(
                'type' => 'File',
                'name' => 'PaypalIpn.ppcrypto',
                //'file' => CONFIGS .'paypal_ipn_config.php'
                'file' => APP."Plugin".DS."paypal_ipn".DS."libs".DS."ppcrypto.php"
            );
//... other codes
//..other functions

function button($title, $options = array(), $buttonOptions = array()) {
//..other codes

$certpath = APP."Plugin".DS."PaypalIpn".DS."Controller".DS."Certificates".DS;

//..other codes

}
?>
```

see this code?

```
$importConfig = array(
                'type' => 'File',
                'name' => 'PaypalIpn.ppcrypto',
                //'file' => CONFIGS .'paypal_ipn_config.php'
                'file' => APP."Plugin".DS."paypal_ipn".DS."libs".DS."ppcrypto.php"
            );
```

and this?

```
$certpath = APP."Plugin".DS."PaypalIpn".DS."Controller".DS."Certificates".DS;
$encryption['paypal_cert_file'] = $certpath.$encryption['paypal_cert_file'];
```

the $importConfig..it was wrong coz it should be

```
$importConfig = array(
                'type' => 'File',
                'name' => 'PaypalIpn.ppcrypto',
                //'file' => CONFIGS .'paypal_ipn_config.php'
                'file' => APP."Plugin".DS."PaypalIpn".DS."libs".DS."ppcrypto.php"
            );
```

..but when i tried to correct it, $encryption['paypal_cert_file'] worked fine. It doesn't ruins/(disables??) my css

i put this as an answer first but i believe there are still questions raising in my head..

Comment: Have you got debugging enabled? This sounds like you might be getting a fatal error before the layout is rendered but after the view.

Comment: yep i enabled it and nothing is being displayed.. no fatal error.. i really wonder what it is becaus this is just merely calling my paypal certificate from a specific directory and DS ruins my css

Comment: Is there anything strange in the HTML output of your page either before or inside the `<head>` section? Does your HTML output have the `<link>` tag for your CSS?

Comment: nothing...but i guess i found the culprit but i dunno if this is somehow related to my problem..please check my answer in a few.. thank you  :)

Comment: One more question. Is `$importConfig` a class property or is it in a method? Ie. Does it have public, private, protected or var before it?

Comment: is use that for this      App::import($importConfig);

Answer (score 1):

I am almost certain whatever is or was wrong is either a fatal error or some kind of other error output messing up your HTML output.

Sometimes even with debugging enabled the error isn't visible on the screen and you must check the HTML source, especially if the error occurs in the `<head>` section of the HTML, inside Javascript or before the closing `>` of a tag. I would suggest that when you fixed the error, it fixed your problem.

I would double check that you have debugging enabled. See [CakePHP Core Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration) from the cake documentation.

If you have fixed the problem but still want to know what caused it, if possible, undo your changes and check what I have mentioned above. Other than that I don't see anything immediately obvious in your code which could have cause the problem.